# Fake compass values in Android

Tags: android, mocking, android-sensors

I'm trying to develop an Android app to mock sensor values (especially compass) for research purposes.
For the GPS sensor I was already implement this part based on a function called `addTestProvider()` within the LocationManager.

I couldn't find a similar method for other sensors.
Does anyone know a way to do that?

Greetings,
dnns